# how to use stylus encoder with symfony encode

Tags: symfony, webpack

I would like to write my styles in stylus in place of sass, but I'm not finding any information to do it.

Here is my actual configuration into `webpack.config.js`:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('web/assets/')
    .setPublicPath('/assets')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/main.js')
    .addStyleEntry('global', './assets/css/global.scss')
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction());

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.enableStylusLoader()` in `Encore` but you need to add stylus and stylus-loader with 
`yarn add stylus stylus-loader --dev`

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom loaders

```
Encore
    // ...
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    })
;
```

Remember to install stylus loader `npm install --save-dev stylus-loader`.

Notice, the configuration of the loader might have changed based on what Webpack version you are using, but I hope you get the general idea.